# MsBuild Error while configuring tf_tutorial_example_trainer.vcxproj

Tags: c++, tensorflow, cmake

Hello their I hope you all are in good health. Actually I want to export my model onto C++ Visual Studio. For this I have to download Tensorflow on windows. I used Tensorflow Docomentation for all this step but while configuring MSBUILD of tf_example I am getting error. I tried almost 7 times but the same error occurs.

I have tried many youtube videos and docomentation but for them these command is working well.  [TensforFlow Cmake Link](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/395cfc42ee3c5842f5383f4049674c012998b133/tensorflow/contrib/cmake/README.md)

I am getting error on.

```
MSBuild /p:Configuration=Release tf_python_build_pip_package.vcxproj
```

Error LOG!

```
arning C4996: 'strncpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider usin
g strncpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See o
nline help for details. [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\
jpeg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.
vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jerror.c(194): war
ning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See onl
ine help for details. [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jp
eg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vc
xproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jerror.c(196): war
ning C4996: 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See onl
ine help for details. [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jp
eg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vc
xproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jmemmgr.c(307): wa
rning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [E
:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj
] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jmemmgr.c(367): wa
rning C4267: '+=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [E
:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj
] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jmemmgr.c(977): wa
rning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [E
:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj
] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jmemmgr.c(991): wa
rning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'long', possible loss of data [E
:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj
] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jmemmgr.c(1107): w
arning C4996: 'getenv': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
 _dupenv_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See on
line help for details. [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\j
peg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.v
cxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jpeg\jmemmgr.c(1110): w
arning C4996: 'sscanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using
 sscanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See onl
ine help for details. [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg\src\jp
eg-build\libjpeg.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\jpeg.vc
xproj]


"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxp
roj" (default target) (1) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_cc_framework.vcxproj" (default
 target) (3) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (defau
lt target) (4) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\proto_text.vcxproj" (default targ
et) (5) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj" (default tar
get) (9) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png_copy_headers_to_destination.v
cxproj" (default target) (26) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png_create_destination_dir.vcxpro
j" (default target) (27) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj" (default target) (28
) ->
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(572): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(588): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(767): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(791): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(228): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uInt', possible loss of data [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj] [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(238): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uInt', possible loss of data [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj] [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(241): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\t
ensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj] [E:\t
ensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(365): war
ning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible los
s of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12
.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(412): war
ning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible los
s of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12
.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(1124): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(1241): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj] [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3356): wa
rning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible lo
ss of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png1
2.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3359): wa
rning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible lo
ss of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png1
2.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3360): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3364): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3379): wa
rning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible lo
ss of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png1
2.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3380): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3383): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(305): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj]
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(322): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj]
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(345): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj]
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(609): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj]
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(947): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj]
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngwutil.c(191): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\t
ensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxproj] [E:\t
ensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngwutil.c(1594): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(572): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(588): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(767): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngpread.c(791): war
ning C4267: '-=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(228): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uInt', possible loss of data [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.vcxpro
j] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(238): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'uInt', possible loss of data [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.vcxpro
j] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(241): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\t
ensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.vcxproj
] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(365): war
ning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible los
s of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12
_static.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(412): war
ning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible los
s of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12
_static.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(1124): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(1241): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\
tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.vcxpro
j] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3356): wa
rning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible lo
ss of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png1
2_static.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3359): wa
rning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible lo
ss of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png1
2_static.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3360): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3364): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3379): wa
rning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible lo
ss of data [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png1
2_static.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3380): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngrutil.c(3383): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(305): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.v
cxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(322): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.v
cxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(345): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.v
cxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(609): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.v
cxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngset.c(947): warni
ng C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of data
 [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.v
cxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngwutil.c(191): war
ning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data [E:\t
ensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_static.vcxproj
] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngwutil.c(1594): wa
rning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of d
ata [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\png12_stati
c.vcxproj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngtest.c(400): warn
ing C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'png_uint_32', possible loss of dat
a [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\pngtest.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngtest.c(1155): war
ning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of dat
a [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\pngtest.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]
  E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png\pngtest.c(1321): war
ning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of dat
a [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png\src\png-build\pngtest.vcxpr
oj] [E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\png.vcxproj]


"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_tutorials_example_trainer.vcxp
roj" (default target) (1) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_cc_framework.vcxproj" (default
 target) (3) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_framework.vcxproj" (defau
lt target) (4) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\proto_text.vcxproj" (default targ
et) (5) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\tf_core_lib.vcxproj" (default tar
get) (9) ->
"E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build\gemmlowp.vcxproj" (default target
) (15) ->
(CustomBuild target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.ta
rgets(171,5): error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1. [E:\tensorflow\tenso
rflow\contrib\cmake\build\gemmlowp.vcxproj]

    139 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:28:05.31

E:\tensorflow\tensorflow\contrib\cmake\build>
```

I need to export my model to Visual studio 2015  on windows 8.1. Thank you guys.

Comment: It is a **requirement** of Stack Overflow to have **textual** representation of the error logs in the question post, *images* doesn't not fit for that purpose. Please, [edit] your question post and copy-paste logs into it. When copy-paste, make sure that **the first error** is copied too - in most situations the first error message is the most important one.

Comment: I first copied the error log but it creating a mess nothing is understandable I am really sorry for that. Next time I will copy paste my error log.

Comment: You may format the log as a *code*: select the log and press `Ctrl+K` or push `{}` button. Do not wait for the next post - edit the current one.

Comment: Kindly view the error I have edited my Question

Comment: It seems that you have lost error messages "hash of ... does not match expected value". But exactly those messages are the **true errors** - others (which you are showing now) are just *warnings* and do not prevent building the project.

Comment: I have go through from all the steps again. I got this error and I have got 139 warning and 1 error in building tf_example. please see the bottom of error log. thank you!

Comment: error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1 view this error

Comment: `error MSB6006: "cmd.exe" exited with code 1.` is a "cumulative" error message - it just means that there are some *other* errors. Given only that error message it is impossible to guess about "what is going wrong".

Comment: I have pasted my whole error log!

Comment: @Tsyvarev is it required to download cuda and give config to tensorflow cpu version ?